# How to create a custom pop-up modal dialog on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to iOS development. I could see Apple's guide about [Modality](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/modality/).
However, I don't know how to implement a custom modal dialog that looks similar to how Gmail app's:
[image: Gmail custom modal dialog]

How should I get started? Are there sample codes anywhere for self-learners to follow along?

Thanks a lot

Comment: have you considered just using simple UIView and another UIView to shadow background, you can place it in the center using autolayout. Recently I have implemented something similar, popup from bottom-up and I could not find any ready solutions either

Comment: here's the link if you want to check out https://gist.github.com/milano95a/dde423af2539b16352a680cdca4a1379#file-basepopupvc-swift

Comment: You can use UIViewController with top, bottom, left, right constraints using an auto-layout or from a storyboard and with a transparent background view.
There will be UIView and this UIView will have imageView and two labels and one button with in the UIView this views will have auto layout constraints respect to UIView

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` examples.

This will allow you to define a custom transition that you could reuse across a number of different view controllers. It also allows you to decouple transition logic from where the modal is being presented or what is being presented.